# Module Articles Category: How to group articles and order by category order?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, overrides, mod-articles-category

I use the Joomla module 'Articles Category' to present articles grouped by category.

Under the 'Grouping Options' tab I selected 'Article Grouping -> Category'.
But it only provides ordering by title. Now I need to be able to order by category order. How do I achieve that?

Overrides / core modifications are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I need to have solved, but usable modification nowhere. So I start to looking for solution on my own.

This is how module orders by articles (helper.php):

```
$articles->setState('list.ordering', $params->get('article_ordering', 'a.ordering'));
```

I am not sure, but after I checked database category columns, there are lft and rgt, which looks that it can be used for ordering. I will be happy if somebody smarter will approve that I am right.

So, I have these categories:

People (lft: 173, rgt: 182)
-- Leaders (lft: 174, rgt: 175)
-- Internal Staff (lft: 176, rgt: 177)
-- External Staff (lft: 178, rgt: 179)
-- Others (lft: 180, rgt: 181)

I need to order only by subcategories as my main category is empty. But as you can see, it can be also used to order main category over the subcategories.

Finally, I just tried to modify article ordering this way and it works!!! :)

```
$articles->setState('list.ordering', 'c.lft, '.$params->get('article_ordering', 'a.ordering'));
```

Maybe it will be also helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you adjust following options in tab 'Filtering Options'
1. Category Filtering Type - Inclusive
2. Category - add all categories you want to show articles from
3. Child Category Articles - if you have them adjust accordingly

Comment: This does not affect ordering of categories when **Grouping Options** is being activated. From there only order by title is being provided.

Comment: You are right. Categories always get sorted by category title, regardless to the order in which they are added to option 2. Category. Only solution then might be view override, but I don't have a time to research that.